# Show transformation is locally invertible

Tags: calculus

$$\begin{pmatrix} x_1\\ x_2\\ x_3\\ \end{pmatrix}= G\begin{pmatrix} u_1\\ u_2\\ u_3\\ \end{pmatrix}$$ with
\begin{align*}
x_1&=u_1+2 \cdot u_3 \\
x_2&=u_3 –2\cdot  u_1 \\
x_3&=u_1+u_2+u_3
\end{align*}
a)   Computer the derivate of this transformation 
For this I have made the matrix :

\begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0 & 2u3 \\ -2u1 & 0 & 1 \\ 1 & 1 & 1\end{bmatrix}

b)   Use the inverse function theorem to show that the transformation is locally invertible if $u_1u_2>0$
The derivative I get is $-1-4\cdot u_1 u_2$   but to satisfy the inverse function theorem all I need to show is that         $-1-4\cdot u_1 u_2$  not equal $0$.  Not sure how I can show that $u1u2 > 0$

Comment: what is u32 ? and what is u12? please use $\LaTeX$

Comment: I set your question in $\LaTeX$ pleas check if i changed the meaning of anything

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The derivative of that transformation should be a $3\times 3$ matrix, and when $u_1 u_2>0$ than the determinant will be not zero, so it is local invertible.

Comment: Thanks for responding. I agree with you but the determinant I get is -1-4U1*U2. but then Anything greater than U1*U2 > -1/4 would make the derivative  -1-U1*U2  > 0. This makes me believe that I am doing something wrong.

Comment: Yeah the subscripts i unterstand, neverthe less the determinant of your matrix would be $-(1+4u_1 u_3)$.

Comment: Thanks again for replying. −(1+2u1u3)   did you mean to say −(1+4u1u3). If it is −(1+2u1u3) I am not sure how that could be. Also, Anything greater than U1*U2 > -1/4 would make the derivative -1-U1*U2 > 0

Comment: yeah i meant $4$, but why do you have $u_2$ and not $u_3$ ? you add something positiv to something positive, or something negative to something negative, so you will never get $0$ anyway

Comment: haha, yes I made a type as well. Thanks for your help. I was just confused why he had set a condition U1*U3 > 0 when U1*U3 > -1/4 satisifies the Inverse function theorem.

Answer (score 0):

As written at the moment the map $G:\ \Bbb R^3\to\Bbb R^3$ is  a linear map with matrix
$$\left[\matrix{1&0&2\cr -2&0&1\cr 1&1&1\cr}\right]\ .$$
The determinant of this matrix is $-5\ne0$. It follows that $G$ is bijective and has an inverse in the sense of linear algebra. This inverse
$$G^{-1}:\quad \Bbb R^3\to\Bbb R^3, \qquad y\mapsto x=G^{-1}y$$
can be considered as a differentiable map in its own right.

$G$ being linear its derivative is  *constant*. To be precise: For any $x\in \Bbb R^3$ we have $dG(x)=G$. This is an immediate consequence of $G(x+h)=G(x)+G(h)$, where $x$ is momentarily fixed and $h$ is a variable tangent vector attached to $x$.

As $\det\bigl(d G(x)\bigr)=\det(G)=-5$ for all $x\in{\mathbb R}^3$ it follows that $G$ is at each $x$ locally invertible in the sense of multivariate calculus. Of course we already knew this, as $G$ is globally linear.